# Why do I get "increment of pointer to unknown structure"?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to bulid a structure named "cache", which holds a container (an array of type List which is already implemented) and an iterator.
when I'm trying to make the iterator point at the next List in the container I get "increment of pointer to unknown structure" and "arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type". I would love an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong:

List is typedefed as follows:

```
typedef struct List_t *List;
```

so List is a pointer to a List_t structure.

Cache is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct cache_t* Cache;

struct cache_t {
    List* container;
    int cache_size;
    List iterator;
};
```

so iterator is a List which is a pointer to a List_t in an array (container).
What I'm trying to do is:

```
cache->iterator ++; //cache is an object of type Cache
```

which, as far as I know, should move iterator by sizeof(List) to the next List in the array. so why am I getting errors?

thanks!

Comment: show the definition of `cache`..

Comment: Show the definition of `struct List_t` which is not there in your posting. If it is not there in your source file as well, the error seems logical, as `struct List_t` is incomplete type, and its size is not known and so its pointer (of type `List`) cannot be incremented.

Comment: Do not `typedef` pointers. That hides the semantics and results in erros as the one you show. Instead, use them only explicitly. (And the name `List` for a pointer is missleading anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer is not incremented by `sizeof(List)` but by `sizeof(struct List_t)`. The definition of `struct List_t` is not there in your source, and is thus an incomplete type. This is the reason for the error.

Comment: thanks! I used a pointe to List (List*) to get the result I wanted